# Julia LoadError: JuliaTeam.toml": No such file or directory

Tags: julia

I just installed JuliaPro and have no previous installations of Julia on the machine. I'm new to Julia so any advice would be appreciated.
I'm running MacOS 10.15.6 and am using JuliaPro_v1.5.1-1.

Here is the problem:

```
julia> using Pkg
julia> Pkg.build("HDF5")

   Building CMake → `~/.julia/packages/CMake/ULbyn/deps/build.log`
   Building Blosc → `~/.julia/packages/Blosc/lzFr0/deps/build.log`
┌ Error: Error building `Blosc`: 
│ ┌ Warning: platform_key() is deprecated, use platform_key_abi() from now on
│ │   caller = ip:0x0
│ └ @ Core :-1
│ ERROR: LoadError: SystemError: opening file "/Applications/JuliaPro-1.5.1-1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/BinaryProvider/JuliaTeam.toml": No such file or directory
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] systemerror(::String, ::Int32; extrainfo::Nothing) at ./error.jl:168
│  [2] #systemerror#48 at ./error.jl:167 [inlined]
│  [3] systemerror at ./error.jl:167 [inlined]
│  [4] open(::String; lock::Bool, read::Nothing, write::Nothing, create::Nothing, truncate::Nothing, append::Nothing) at ./iostream.jl:284
│  [5] open at ./iostream.jl:273 [inlined]
│  [6] open(::Base.var"#294#295"{Tuple{}}, ::String; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at ./io.jl:323
│  [7] open at ./io.jl:323 [inlined]
│  [8] read at ./io.jl:408 [inlined]
│  [9] parsefile at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/Pkg/ext/TOML/src/TOML.jl:50 [inlined]
│  [10] redirect_download_target(::String) at /Users/d3k137/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/IjWSK/src/JuliaTeam.jl:35
│  [11] (::BinaryProvider.JuliaTeam.var"#1#2"{BinaryProvider.var"#54#81"{BinaryProvider.var"#36#63"{String}}})(::String, ::String) at /Users/d3k137/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/IjWSK/src/JuliaTeam.jl:18
│  [12] download(::String, ::String; verbose::Bool) at /Users/d3k137/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/IjWSK/src/PlatformEngines.jl:608
│  [13] download_verify(::String, ::String, ::String; verbose::Bool, force::Bool, quiet_download::Bool) at /Users/d3k137/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/IjWSK/src/PlatformEngines.jl:692
│  [14] install(::String, ::String; prefix::Prefix, tarball_path::String, force::Bool, ignore_platform::Bool, verbose::Bool) at /Users/d3k137/.julia/packages/BinaryProvider/IjWSK/src/Prefix.jl:314
│  [15] top-level scope at /Users/d3k137/.julia/packages/Blosc/lzFr0/deps/build.jl:45
│  [16] include(::String) at ./client.jl:457
│  [17] top-level scope at none:5
│ in expression starting at /Users/d3k137/.julia/packages/Blosc/lzFr0/deps/build.jl:41
└ @ Pkg.Operations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by upgrading your `Blosc.jl` to `v0.7.0` (Or Higher), you can execute `Pkg.update()` in your JuliaPro installation, `Pkg` should take care of the upgrade.